# Unable to fetch some content using createDocumentFromUrl in vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I've written some code in vba to get the movie names from a torrent website using `.createDocumentFromUrl()` method. As I've never worked with this method and haven't found any remarkable information either on it to successfully go with, I get stuck. I have tried to create a script, though.

Here is my try:

```
Sub Fromurl_Method()
    Const URL As String = "https://yts.am/browse-movies"
    Dim hStart As HTMLDocument, hdoc As HTMLDocument

    Set hStart = New HTMLDocument
    Set hdoc = hStart.createDocumentFromUrl(URL, vbNullString)

    Do While hdoc.readyState = "loading" Or hdoc.readyState = "interactive": DoEvents: Loop
    Debug.Print hdoc.DocumentElement.innerHTML
End Sub
```

When I execute the above script, it fetches some html elements which are not from that website. I took a closer look into the elements I have parsed and noticed this line on the top `This content cannot be displayed in a frame`. It is behaving the same way with most of the sites. How can I make it successful? Thanks in advance.
Once again, my intention is to parse all the movie names from that site using `.createDocumentFromUrl()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Get_Info()

Dim Elems, e As Variant

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE& = 4&
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = Nothing
DoEvents

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
DoEvents

With ie
    .Visible = false
    .Navigate "https://yts.am/browse-movies"
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
End With

Dim i As Double

With ie.Document
    Set Elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
    DoEvents
    i = 2
    For Each e In Elems
        If e.getAttribute("class") = "browse-movie-title" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = e.innerText
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next e

End With

Set Elems = Nothing
Set e = Nothing

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code above will give you a list of all movies. Just modify the code to adapt it to your needs of getting the first one if you only need the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Foxfire And Burns And Burns. If you thought that the movie names I'm after by any means, then it's a slight misunderstanding of your's. I only wish to know how to work with `.createDocumentFromUrl()`. Hope you got me.

Comment: Ops! My bad then. Sorry about it. Now I understand :)